# How can I return a HTTP 400 response when a specific exception occurs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I'm using spring MVC and with a relational database. One of the tables Spring writes to has a uniqueness constraint which works as expected.

Right now if a request comes in that violates that constraint the exception `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException` is thrown and an HTTP 500 response (internal server error) is returned, but really there is no issue with system but with the request of the user.

What is the most natural way to catch the exception and return a HTTP 400 (bad request)? I could actually catch it like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<BaseMaterial> insert(@RequestBody BaseMaterial baseMaterial) {
    try {           
        baseMaterial.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        baseMaterialService.insert(baseMaterial);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(baseMaterial);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
}
```

But then I'd have to do that for every one of my endpoints. I'd also prefer to use just the POJO without the `ResponseEntity` wrapper.

Thanks!

Comment: use `@ControllerAdvice`.

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for answering my own question but I found what I was [looking for on spring's blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

In your controller class, create a method that will run when the desired exception is thrown and annotate it with `ExceptionHandler` and `ResponseStatus`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DuplicateKeyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT, reason = "Data integrity violation") // 409
public void conflict() {
    // code goes here
}
```

And that's it. No other changes!

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe it's actually a problem with the system/server. I'd say you should check for duplicates before inserting. Check if a row already exists with the given unique field and then throw an exception if true.

Comment: I thought of that too but I reasoned that that would require two database calls vs one and that it's okay to have the DB tell me there are duplicates.

Comment: But you don't want the rest call to fail over and over because of your unique constraint (The user might be stupid). That's a huge nasty exception. You wan't to handle it and avoid those kind of exceptions so that you're in charge of whats going on. Sorry for my english but I hope you understand :)